# Can't move MP3 file to a different folder

Tags: java, file-rename

I am trying to move some MP3 files to different folders using `File.renameTo()`, however it just keeps not working I don't know why.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong, please?

```
File songsFolder = new File("songs");
File[] songsList = songsFolder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < allSongs.size(); i++) {
    //allSongs is an ArrayList defined earlier
    File music = (File) songsList[i];
    FileInputStream fileMusic = new FileInputStream(music);
    int size = (int) music.length();
    fileMusic.skip(size - 128);
    byte[] last128 = new byte[128];
    fileMusic.read(last128);
    String id3 = new String(last128);
    String tag = id3.substring(0, 3);

    if (musicsList[i].isFile()) {
        File afile = songsList[i];
        if (afile.renameTo(new File("songs/" + id3.substring(33, 62).trim() + "/" + songsList[i].getName()))) {
            System.out.println("File moved successfully!");
        } else {
            System.out.println("File failed to move!");
        }
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
File failed to move!
File failed to move!
File failed to move!
File failed to move!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the directory `"songs/" + id3.substring(33, 62).trim()` already exist? `File.renameTo()` will not create the directory for you.

Try something like this:

```
File afile = songsList[i];
File newDir = new File("songs", id3.substring(33, 62).trim());
newDir.mkdirs();
File newName = new File(newDir, afile.getName());
afile.renameTo(newName);
```

Comment: The directory already exists.
But with this method it worked just fine. Thanks, dude :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to close `FileInputStream`s before attempting to rename the associated files. You should generally close such resource when done with it.

Further, you should check whether the target directory really exists.

If you are programming under Java 7 you should try the new java.nio.file API. This offers a move method throwing an exception telling you more about the reason instead of just returning `false`.

Comment: Well, I closed the FileInputStream before the first if but still, can't move any file.

Comment: I extended the answer.

Comment: I read about that API and it seems interesting, however I don't know how to use it. I don't even know if I have to install something first or not. Yes it's kinda lamme but I am just an aspiring programmer. However I managed to make my code work. But thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: If you have a java.io.File f1 that you want to rename to a file f2 you could simply do a `java.nio.file.Files.move(f1.toPath(), f2.toPath());`